# Fill up a function with unspecified number of arguments in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

```
$my_object->$setValue[1](foo, bar, x, y, z....nth);
```

My problem is that, values to be passed inside setValue is dynamic. Meaning, it can pass as many values. I don't know the proper implementation for this, I've imagined it like this, and I know it is not working:

```
$my_object->$setValue[1](

    for($param = 0; $param > $param_count; $param++){

    }
);
```

Please help or could you please me help in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Make it an array:
`$my_object->$setValue[1] = array(foo, bar, x, y, z....nth);`

then just: 
`foreach ($my_object->$setValue[1] as $item){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`func_num_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) functions. For example:

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

**Edit:** To pass unknown number of arguments to a function, you can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array(array($my_object, $setValue[1]), array("one", "two", ...));
```